# Is this square root approximation correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

Playing around I found a series which looks to converge to the square root function.

$$\sqrt{p^2+q}\overset{?}{=}p\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(-\frac q{2p^2}\right)^n\right)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem for what your formula want to be.

Comment: The link you point out only applies near 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it is not correct.  Your right-hand expression is a geometric series for $$p\left(1-\frac{-\frac q{2p^2}}{1+\frac q{2p^2}}\right),$$
which is a rational expression in $p$ and $q$.

The correct answer is given by Newton's ["generalized binomial theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem), in the form $$\sqrt{p^2+q}=p\sqrt{1+q/p^2} = p\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{1/2} k \left(\frac q {p^2}\right)^k,$$ which converges for $|q/p^2|<1$.
The first two values of $\binom{1/2} k$ are $1$ and  $1/2$, which match what you have.  But $\binom{1/2}{2}=-1/8$ which does not match your $-1/4$.

Comment: Thanks for the formula, but saying that the series does not have terms equal to yours is not enough to show that the sums are different.

Comment: What would it take?  These formulas are not just advertising slogans or song lyrics.  One is right and one is wrong.  Why don't you tell us why you think your formula is correct.

Comment: I have no idea if mine is correct. I'm just saying that two different series can converge to the same value and therefore your response doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Blincer A function can only ever be represented by one power series centered at a fixed point.

Comment: That was missing from the explanation then. Thank you!

Comment: There is a sign error.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.

$$p\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(-\frac q{2p^2}\right)^n\right)=p\left(1+\frac q{2p^2}\frac1{1+\dfrac q{2p^2}}\right)=p+\frac{pq}{2p^2+q}\ne\sqrt{p^2+q}.$$